# Multiple themes in rails 4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

What is the best way to have multiple themes in a rails project. I have a CMS and a website. And my vendor looks now like this

```
vendor
 |-- images/
 |    |-- <images>
 |-- javascripts/
 |    |-- <javascripts>
 |-- stylesheets/
 |    |-- <css>
 |
```

I want it to look like this:

```
vendor
 |-- cms --images/
 |         |-- <images>
 |       --javascripts/
 |         |-- <javascripts>
 |       -- stylesheets/
 |         |-- <css>
 |
 |-- web --images/
 |         |-- <images>
 |       --javascripts/
 |         |-- <javascripts>
 |       --stylesheets/
 |         |-- <css>
```

If I do this.. how do I "require" them in application.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 application.css.
for example `application.cms.css` and `application.web.css`, it same as application.css

Require your cms css files in application.cms.css. Also require web css files in application.web.css.

And add precompile path,

```
# config/application.rb or initializers/assets.rb <- depend on rails version
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['application.cms.css', 'application.web.css']
```

And include `application.cms.css` or `application.web.css` in layout html file depend on your condition.

Comment: I did that, but I wanted to organize them in subfolders, since there are a lot of .js files,  .css files and images related to those themes. Doing it this way I need a "cms" subdirectory and "web" subdirectory on "stylesheets" and "javascripts" folders.

Comment: What is your question? you asked 'how do I "require" them in application.css?', not organizing

Comment: hmm sorry.. I misunderstood your answer.. You are right, that will solve it.. Thanks for your time.